# Remove class of a div when clicking on another in vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, class, addeventlistener, queryselector

(Sorry for my English, it's not my native language)

I created a function that widens a wrapper containing a visible small element and display an invisible element (map). If I click on another wrapper, the function works as well, but I would like to cancel the effect on the first wrapper.

Can you help me?

```
wrapper.forEach((wrapperElement)=> {
    let mapElement = wrapperElement.querySelector(".map");

    wrapperElement.addEventListener('click', function reset(){ 
        mapElement.classList.toggle('show');
        wrapperElement.classList.toggle('focus');

    });
});
```

I think I should attribute isWiden = true to the first wrapper, and the function would test it before targeting the second wrapper. But I'm struggling to do that.

**Edit :**

I listened some of your advices and it resolved part of the problem, meaning that when I open a div, it closes the others ! But now, I can't close the one I just opened. I see where is the contradiction in my loop, but I don't know how to change it.

```
const wrapper = document.querySelectorAll(".wrapper");


wrapper.forEach((wrapperElement)=> {
    let mapElement = wrapperElement.querySelector(".map");

    wrapperElement.addEventListener('click', function(){ 
        
            wrapper.forEach((el) => {
                let map = el.querySelector(".map");
                map.classList.remove('show');
                el.classList.remove('focus');
            });

                mapElement.classList.add('show');
                wrapperElement.classList.add('focus');
     });
});
```

Comment: It's called an accordion I think

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to figure out how to determine which other element is currently "shown" so you can "hide" it?  You shouldn't need to.  Hide *all* of them, then show the one that was clicked.  Elements which are already hidden have no effect, but if one of them is shown it becomes hidden.

Comment: Instead of toggling show/focus on child elements, you could simply add a class to the wrapper and change your css selectors accordingly. Then when you click a wrapper, you turn off the class on all others.